# C: Sockets without stop and wait

Tags: c, sockets, nonblocking

I'm creating a tftp-like program but instead of stop and wait, I'm trying to use a go-back-n approach. I'm not exactly sure how to go about this as I have very little socket programming experience.

I have my client sending all of the data with sendto, and am currently just not calling recvfrom because it will wait until I get a response, but I don't want it to wait. I want to check if there was a response, but if not, keep sending data.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Please let me know if more information is needed, I'm having trouble elaborating.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a non-blocking socket and use `select()` (or `poll()` or whatever other mechanism you have at hand) to wait for both writability and readability of the socket. Then respond appropriately to each state independently when it arises.

I've never done this with UDP, but I see no reason that it shouldn't (a quick Google seems to reaffirm that).